# One app service plan, 2 app services, 1 wildcard cert, 2 deployments. How do i avoid Certificate conflicts?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I currently have a situation where i'm deploying 2 App Services into a new App Service Plan together.

Both App Services use the same certificate - *.test.myapp.internal

The App Services must be deployed independently of one another.

Right now, both have the exact same ARM Template resource code to deploy a Microsoft.Web/certificates resource with them, and link it to the hostnamebinding.

I deployed the first app service, and all went smoothly, my certificate was read from a keyvault, and copied to the resource group of the first application.
The application was then able to use the certificate, and worked well.

Next, i went to deploy the second app service, which also lives in it's own resource group. This time i was met with an error message stating that there's a conflict with the certificate resource, and that a certificate with that thumbprint already exists.

> Another certificate exists with same thumbprint xxxx in xxxx... etc.

I'm running my ARM Template in the Create or Update mode (Incremental) - so i would assume that as i'm supplying the exact same name for the certificate in both templates - and therefore it exists already, it would just be skipped.

So - how can I skip the certificate resource being created? Clearly it exists, and i could use it with the second App Service. As far as i can tell, there's no "exists" style function in ARM.

EDIT: Had an idea where I can set a parameter and do conditional logic on whether to deploy that resource or not. However, i'm not sure that works when i have the "dependsOn" part set for other resources. i.e. the site or hostnamebinding depending on the cert to be deployed. Guess i've got some testing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is: You can't do conditional checks on an item already existing in an ARM Template.

The Solution to this was:
Have a seperate resource group that hosts your App Service Plan, and have that resource group contain the Certificates. The certificates can be created from a KeyVault secret of course, which then links them to the Key Vault.
This way you can utilise the Certificates from a 'central' location you already reference with the App Service Plan.

This then gives you the possibility to have x number of resource groups with your App Services in - which reference the App Service Plan, and the certificates in your seperate 'central' resource group.

This makes the initial deploy of the APIs the same as every deploy after - as there's no need to deploy certificates too.

So, for 'One app service plan, 2 app services, 1 wildcard cert, 2 deployments' you need 3 ARM Templates:

1. App Service Plan & Certificates
2. App Service x & whatever other stuff supporting it
3. App Service y & whatever other stuff supporting it

Deploy order is: 1, 2, 3. Or, 1, 3, 2. Or 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2... etc As long as Template 1. is deployed first.

I hope this can help someone who had trouble with something that looked 'simple' on the surface.